# VB.NET Delete specific number of last characters in string in excel

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel

I have a column where I have an ID. I have to match data from one file with other, however in one table there is pure ID, in the other there are ID+year, so I have to delete four last characters in every cell of that column. I tried this:

```
For i=2 to ArraySize
    ExWorkSheet.Cells(i, ColumnNumber) = ExWorkSheet.Cells(i, ColumnNumber).remove(len(string)-4,4)
Next
```

This code works but it is very slow. I have 17k+ rows in table.
I also tried to use function replace, it is faster because it works on whole range, but it delete every string 2017(or 2016, etc.), even if it is in the middle of ID.

Comment: can you describe  id and  id+year sampe?

Comment: why is there a [tag:vb.net] here?

Comment: It is a number about 8-15 digits

Comment: If you do, what you wrote in your comment below this may result in IDs that are no longer unique (e.g. use IDs 1232017456 and 1220173456). So you will get problems if you try to link your sheets together...

Comment: I concatenate this "short" ID with date which is in another column, so it is still unique.

Answer (score 1):

Its way faster to read the range into an array, process the array and write it back.

Try the following code:

```
Sub del_4_chars()
Const ColumnNumber As Integer = 4
Dim Arr, ArraySize As Long, I As Long
ArraySize = 100
    Arr = ExWorkSheet.Range(Cells(2, ColumnNumber), Cells(ArraySize, ColumnNumber)).Value2
    For I = 1 To ArraySize - 1
        Arr(I, 1) = Left(Arr(I, 1), Len(Arr(I, 1)) - 4)
    Next I
    ExWorkSheet.Range(Cells(2, ColumnNumber), Cells(ArraySize, ColumnNumber)).Value2 = Arr
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

same coding upper.

```
Dim vDB, rngDB As Range
Set rngDB = ExWorkSheet.Cells(2, ColumnNumber).Resize(arraysize)
vDB = rngDB
For i = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1)
    vDB(i, 1) = Left(vDB(i, 1), Len(vDB(i, 1)) - 4)
Next i
rngDB = vDB
```

Comment: I have actually solve this problem in different way. I use function replace in both files, so if I delete too much digits, it happens in both files. But thanks for help !